# Download .xls files from a webpage using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to download all the `.xls` or `.xlsx` or `.csv` from this website into a specified folder.

```
https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009
```

I have looked into mechanize, beautiful soup, urllib2 etc. Mechanize does not work in Python 3, urllib2 also had problems with Python 3, I looked for workaround but I couldn't. So, I am currently trying to make it work using Beautiful Soup.

I found some example code and attempted to modify it to suit my problem, as follows -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009/'
u = urlopen(url)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in soup.select('div[webpartid] a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if href.startswith('javascript:'):
        continue
    filename = href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    href = urljoin(url, quote(href))
    try:
        urlretrieve(href, filename)
    except:
        print('failed to download')
```

However, when run this code does not extract the files from the target page, nor output any failure message (e.g. 'failed to download').

- How can I use BeautifulSoup to select the Excel files from the page?
- How can I download these files to a local file using Python?

Comment: Can you describe in what way your code "didn't work"? The posted code is wrongly indented so would not run at all.

Comment: The code just ran sometimes but never created any file. Regarding the indentation, I apologies while posting I must have spoiled that but rest assured that when I ran the code, I did take care of indentation

Comment: I have a working solution for this problem however the question is closed so I can no longer post it. I've posted it as a Gist here https://gist.github.com/mfitzp/29522e2ac4057bf01745

Comment: @ mfitzp Thanks a ton, this worked. Its people like you who ensure a language does not ever die!!!!

Comment: Adding these lines: < import os as os      os.chdir("path here") > and you can provide the downloading location for the code that mfitzp wrote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issues with your script as it stand are:

1. The `url` has a trailing `/` which gives an invalid page when requested, not listing the files you want to download.
2. The CSS selector in `soup.select(...)` is selecting `div` with the attribute `webpartid` which does not exist anywhere in that linked document.
3. You are joining the URL and quoting it, even though the links are given in the page as absolute URLs and they do not need quoting.
4. The `try:...except:` block is stopping you seeing the errors generated when trying to download the file. Using an `except` block without a specific exception is bad practise and should be avoided.

A modified version of your code that *will* get the correct files and attempt to download them is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
from urllib.parse import urljoin

# Remove the trailing / you had, as that gives a 404 page
url = 'https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009'
u = urlopen(url)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Select all A elements with href attributes containing URLs starting with http://
for link in soup.select('a[href^="http://"]'):
    href = link.get('href')

    # Make sure it has one of the correct extensions
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv','.xls','.xlsx']):
        continue

    filename = href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href, filename) )
    urlretrieve(href, filename)
    print("Done.")
```

However, if you run this you'll notice that a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` exception is thrown, even though the file is downloadable in the browser. 
At first I thought this was a referral check (to prevent hotlinking), however if you watch at the request in your browser (e.g. Chrome Developer tools) you'll notice that
the initial `http://` request is blocked there also, and then Chrome attempts a `https://` request for the same file.

In other words, the request must go via HTTPS to work (despite what the URLs in the page say). To fix this you will need to rewrite the `http:` to `https:` before using the URL for the request. The following code will correctly modify the URLs and download the files. I've also added an variable to specify the output folder, which is added to the filename using `os.path.join`:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

URL = 'https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009'
OUTPUT_DIR = ''  # path to output folder, '.' or '' uses current folder

u = urlopen(URL)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for link in soup.select('a[href^="http://"]'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv','.xls','.xlsx']):
        continue

    filename = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])

    # We need a https:// URL for this site
    href = href.replace('http://','https://')

    print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href, filename) )
    urlretrieve(href, filename)
    print("Done.")
```

Comment: Beautifully explained, I realize I have so much to learn. I am so grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a good working example, using the `BeautifulSoup4`, `requests`, and `wget` modules for Python 2.7:

```
import requests
import wget
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

url = 'https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009'

file_types = ['.xls', '.xlsx', '.csv']

for file_type in file_types:

    response = requests.get(url)

    for link in BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            if file_type in link['href']:
                full_path = url + link['href']
                wget.download(full_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i tried above code still giving me urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden


Also tried by adding user agents my modified code


import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen, urlretrieve

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
URL = Request('https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009', headers=headers)

#URL = 'https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009'

OUTPUT_DIR = 'E:\python\out'  # path to output folder, '.' or '' uses current folder

u = urlopen(URL)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for link in soup.select('a[href^="http://"]'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv','.xls','.xlsx']):
        continue

    filename = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])

    # We need a https:// URL for this site
    href = href.replace('http://','https://')

    print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href, filename) )
    urlretrieve(href, filename)
    print("Done.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me ... using python3

```
import os
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve
from urllib.error import HTTPError

URL = 'https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/bs_viewcontent.aspx?Id=2009'
OUTPUT_DIR = ''  # path to output folder, '.' or '' uses current folder

u = urlopen(URL)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for link in soup.select('a[href^="http://"]'):
    href = link.get('href')
if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv','.xls','.xlsx']):
    continue

filename = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])

# We need a https:// URL for this site
href = href.replace('http://','https://')

try:
    print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href, filename) )
    urlretrieve(href, filename)
    print("Done.")
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    if err.code == 404:
        continue
```