# How to download .qrs files from a website using python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to download all the files ending with .qrs, .dat, .hea and store them to a local folder from this website.

[https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/](https://physionet.org/content/shareedb/1.0.0/)

I tried modifying the solution from the following link.

[Download .xls files from a webpage using Python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632838/download-xls-files-from-a-webpage-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

This is how I modified the code:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

URL = 'https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/'
OUTPUT_DIR = ''  # path to output folder, '.' or '' uses current folder

u = urlopen(URL)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for link in soup.select('a[href^="https://"]'): # or a[href*="shareedb/0"]
    href = link.get('href')
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.dat','.hea','.qrs']):
        continue

    filename = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])

    # We need a https:// URL for this site
    # href = href.replace('http://','https://')

    print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href, filename) )
    urlretrieve(href, filename)
    print("Done.")
```

When I run this code,  it does not extract the files from the target page, nor outputs any failure message (e.g. 'failed to download').

After some debugging I saw that in my case non of the files are being selected. I suspect that it has to do more with the structure of the html.

How can I download these files to a local directory using Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the excellent [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library as follows:

```
import bs4            
import requests

url = "https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    href = link['href']

    if any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.dat','.hea','.qrs']):
        print "Downloading '{}'".format(href)
        remote_file = requests.get(url + href)

        with open(href, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in remote_file.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
                if chunk: 
                    f.write(chunk)
```

This would download all `.dat`, `.hea` and `.qrs` files to your computer.

Install using the standard:

```
pip install requests
```

Note, all of the hrefs on that URL are already in a form suitable for using directly as a filename (so no need at the moment to parse away any `/` characters).

Comment: I tried also your solution which works fine. Can you please explain why it is taking so long to download the files?

Comment: It is probably a limit on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the clean code. Although @Teemu Risikko gave a very good response that works, your solution provides a different approach, but it is also a little bit more efficient because it downloads the files in less time.
Can you please tell me or guess why it is faster, although you are using a nested loop?

Comment: If you have `lxml` installed, this would make the soup parsing slightly quicker. You can also experiment with different chunk sizes, but I doubt that would make much difference overall.

Comment: The first loop is just getting the `hrefs`, with the second one doing the downloads. Note, this approach is designed to also work with very large files. If you are sure the files are always small, a non-chunked solution could also be used.

Comment: I also agree that this is a better method: requests is a great library, I definitely recommend to use it. My answer was more of a "why it does not work currently" and "make it work with minimal changes to the original" -type of thing.

Comment: @Teemu Risikko thanks for spending time to the problem. Thank you also for not deleting the answer. Now other people can see  alternative solutions and compare them or choose which one fits the best.

Answer (score 1):

To expand the answer by wolf tian, the select does not find anything because the links in that site do not have `"https://"` (nor do they have a `"shareedb"`) in their href. The files you are trying to download all have the structure `<a href="01911.hea">01911.hea</a>`. Their path is *relative*. So what you need to do is first extract those filenames for example like this:

```
for link in soup.select('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not href or not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.dat','.hea','.qrs']):
        continue

    filename = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, href)
```

And then you need to apply the host part to the URL before retrieving it:

```
urlretreive(URL + href, filename)
```

Comment: With this approach it downloads the files but very slowly, I also had to add
if href is not None:

Comment: Now it should be ok for the if-part. The file size for example 01911.dat seems to be "only" 1.9MiB, but when I try to open it directly from the browser it takes a really long time then too.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

start_url = 'https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/'
r = requests.get(start_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# get full url of file
pre = soup.find('pre')
file_urls = pre.select('a[href*="."]')
full_urls = [urljoin(start_url, url['href'])for url in file_urls]
# download file
for full_url in full_urls:
    file_name = full_url.split('/')[-1]
    print("Downloading {} to {}...".format(full_url, file_name))
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        fr = requests.get(full_url, stream=True)
        for chunk in fr.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            f.write(chunk)
    print('Done')
```

out:

```
Downloading https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/01911.dat to 01911.dat...
Done
Downloading https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/01911.hea to 01911.hea...
Done
Downloading https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/01911.qrs to 01911.qrs...
Done
Downloading https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/02012.dat to 02012.dat...
Done
Downloading https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/02012.hea to 02012.hea...
Done
Downloading https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/shareedb/02012.qrs to 02012.qrs...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From you symptom, the possible reason may be that no matched url then it don't enter into the loop.
Due to I use python 2.7.
I don't verify the code.
You may try to print the link you matched and then check whether the urls can be downloaded and extracted.

Comment: Exactly that is the case, the condition 
if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.dat','.hea','.qrs']): is never satisfied and the loop continues back to the start.