# Crawling csv files from a url with dropdown list?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl monthly data (csv files) from [Weather Canada](https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/hourly_data_e.html?hlyRange=2004-09-24%7C2020-03-03&dlyRange=2018-05-14%7C2020-03-03&mlyRange=%7C&StationID=43403&Prov=NS&urlExtension=_e.html&searchType=stnProx&optLimit=yearRange&StartYear=1840&EndYear=2020&selRowPerPage=25&Line=0&txtRadius=50&optProxType=city&selCity=44%7C40%7C63%7C36%7CHalifax&selPark=&txtCentralLatDeg=&txtCentralLatMin=0&txtCentralLatSec=0&txtCentralLongDeg=&txtCentralLongMin=0&txtCentralLongSec=0&txtLatDecDeg=&txtLongDecDeg=&timeframe=1&Year=2020&Month=1&Day=1#).

Normally one needs to select the year/month/day from the dropdown list and click on the "GO" and then click the "Download Data" button for that data of the selected month + year, as below.
[image]
I'd like to download all data files in CSV from all available month/year in python (with beautifulsoup 4).

I tried to modify some codes from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632838/download-xls-files-from-a-webpage-using-python-and-beautifulsoup), but hasn't been successful. Please help.
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    # Python 3.x
    from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

```
# Removed the trailing / from the URL
urlJan2020 = 
'''https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/hourly_data_e.html?hlyRange=2004-09-24%7C2020-03-03&dlyRange=2018-05-14%7C2020-03-03&mlyRange=%7C&StationID=43403&Prov=NS&urlExtension=_e.html&searchType=stnProx&optLimit=yearRange&StartYear=1840&EndYear=2020&selRowPerPage=25&Line=0&txtRadius=50&optProxType=city&selCity=44%7C40%7C63%7C36%7CHalifax&selPark=&txtCentralLatDeg=&txtCentralLatMin=0&txtCentralLatSec=0&txtCentralLongDeg=&txtCentralLongMin=0&txtCentralLongSec=0&txtLatDecDeg=&txtLongDecDeg=&timeframe=1&Year=2020&Month=1&Day=1#'''
u = urlopen(urlJan2020)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Select all A elements that have an href attribute, starting with http://
for link in soup.select('a[href^="http://"]'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv','.xls','.xlsx']):
        continue

    filename = href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

    # You don't need to join + quote as URLs in the HTML are absolute.
    # However, we need a https:// URL (in spite of what the link says: check request in your web browser's developer tools)
    href = href.replace('http://','https://')

    print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href, filename) )
    urlretrieve(href, filename)
    print("Done.")
```

Comment: for all month and years ? how about day ?

Comment: All days will be there if month and year are selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def Main():
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for year in range(2019, 2021):
            for month in range(1, 13):
                r = req.post(
                    f"https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=43403&Year={year}&Month={month}&Day=1&timeframe=1&submit=Download+Data")
                name = r.headers.get(
                    "Content-Disposition").split("_", 5)[-1][:-1]
                with open(name, 'w') as f:
                    f.write(r.text)
                print(f"Saved {name}")


Main()
```

Comment: for some reason the parse and rewrittened data doesn't look the same with downloaded data- there were 32 columns (up to column AE) in the downloaded csv file, but 28 columns (up to column AB) with hourly data (I definetly needed this) I wonder how name = r.headers.get(
                    "Content-Disposition").split("_", 5)[-1][:-1] . worked.

Comment: @Meruemu give an example  for specific `month/year` so i can check on my end ? https://pasteboard.co/IXyrmih.png

Comment: I downloaded from here. https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/daily_data_e.html?hlyRange=2004-09-24%7C2020-03-03&dlyRange=2018-05-14%7C2020-03-03&mlyRange=%7C&StationID=43403&Prov=NS&urlExtension=_e.html&searchType=stnProx&optLimit=yearRange&StartYear=1840&EndYear=2020&selRowPerPage=25&Line=0&txtRadius=50&optProxType=city&selCity=44%7C40%7C63%7C36%7CHalifax&selPark=&txtCentralLatDeg=&txtCentralLatMin=0&txtCentralLatSec=0&txtCentralLongDeg=&txtCentralLongMin=0&txtCentralLongSec=0&txtLatDecDeg=&txtLongDecDeg=&timeframe=2&Day=1&Year=2020&Month=2#

Comment: It's feb 2020 file which contained daily since 1/1/2020 till Feb.

Comment: I figured out you parsed hourly data, and I downloaded daily data. So no issue. Thanks again.@αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη

Comment: @Meruemu yea it could happen due to my break hours haha. still need help ? it's just a parameter to replace.?